# conditionally enable tool bar option in list tab in maximo

Tags: maximo

Is there a way to conditionally enable change status icon in List tab of any application in Maximo 7.5/7.6 . For example the change status option should be visible when the list tab has PO's which are in DRAFT status.

Answer (score 0):

**Maximo is working as design for the following reasons:**

1. Conditional UI can only operate within the context of a record because on the main tab you have a record in the databean.
2. When on the list tab you are only in the resultsetbean so the calculations are not the same, hence it doesn't get evaluated on the
   list tab, only on the details page of the record.
3. Restrictions **cannot** not being applied on a **list tab** at this point.

Refer 
[the Tech Note](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21663787)